# Fetching only the first matched document with condition in mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

Here's is my collection

```
[
    {
        _id: "585be0da13385513689f704a",
        site: "NBT",
        url: "m.nbt.com",
        label: "NBT Home",
        platform: "mobile",
        speed: 61,
        date: "2016-12-22T14:18:57.975Z"
    },
    {
        _id: "585be0da13385513689f704b",
        site: "NBT",
        url: "nbt.com",
        label: "NBT Home",
        platform: "desktop",
        speed: 75,
        date: "2016-12-22T14:15:57.975Z"
    },
    {
        _id: "585be0da13385513689f704c",
        site: "MT",
        url: "m.mt.com",
        label: "MT Home",
        platform: "mobile",
        speed: 40,
        date: "2016-12-22T14:01:57.975Z"
    },
    {
        _id: "585be0da13385513689f704d",
        site: "NBT",
        url: "m.nbt.com",
        label: "NBT Home",
        platform: "mobile",
        speed: 90,
        date: "2016-12-22T12:18:57.975Z"
    }
]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[
    {
        _id: "585be0da13385513689f704b",
        site: "NBT",
        url: "nbt.com",
        label: "NBT Home",
        platform: "desktop",
        speed: 75,
        date: "2016-12-22T14:15:57.975Z"
    },
    {
        _id: "585be0da13385513689f704c",
        site: "MT",
        url: "m.mt.com",
        label: "MT Home",
        platform: "mobile",
        speed: 40,
        date: "2016-12-22T14:01:57.975Z"
    },
    {
        _id: "585be0da13385513689f704d",
        site: "NBT",
        url: "m.nbt.com",
        label: "NBT Home",
        platform: "mobile",
        speed: 90,
        date: "2016-12-22T12:18:57.975Z"
    }
]
```

Basically I want first matched distinct (label + platform) combination documents.

As you can see in the colloection, label- NBT Home is present in 3 documents but I would want to retrieve only unique combination of label + platform. So NBT Home for mobile and NBT Home for desktop is what I'm expecting.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group:{
         _id:{
            label:"$label",
            platform:"$platform"
         },
         site:{
            $first:"$site"
         },
         url:{
            $first:"$url"
         },
         speed:{
            $first:"$speed"
         }
      }
   }
])
```

output:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "label" : "MT Home",
        "platform" : "mobile"
    },
    "site" : "MT",
    "url" : "m.mt.com",
    "speed" : 40
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "label" : "NBT Home",
        "platform" : "desktop"
    },
    "site" : "NBT",
    "url" : "nbt.com",
    "speed" : 75
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "label" : "NBT Home",
        "platform" : "mobile"
    },
    "site" : "NBT",
    "url" : "m.nbt.com",
    "speed" : 61
}
```

Comment: This is returning only 2 records however expected output has 3.

Comment: MT Home and NBT Home+mobile is returned. NBT Home + desktop is missing.

Comment: @MohitRathi take another look at the output I posted, 3 docs are returned and NBT home + desktop is present. This is the result of the aggregation query on the sample docs you provided...

Answer (score -1):

Use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) in aggregation pipeline and then use [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/)

Below query is written using $first.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{ "_id":{"label":"$label", "platform":"$platform"}, "site": {"$first":"$site"}, "url": {"$first":"$url"}, "speed":{"$first":"$speed"}, "date":{"$first":"$date"} } }])
```

For a sample collection with following records

```
db.collection.find()


{ "_id" : "585be0da13385513689f704a", "site" : "NBT", "url" : "m.nbt.com", "labe
l" : "NBT Home", "platform" : "mobile", "speed" : 61, "date" : "2016-12-22T14:18
:57.975Z" }
{ "_id" : "585be0da13385513689f704b", "site" : "NBT", "url" : "nbt.com", "label"
 : "NBT Home", "platform" : "desktop", "speed" : 75, "date" : "2016-12-22T14:15:
57.975Z" }
{ "_id" : "585be0da13385513689f704c", "site" : "MT", "url" : "m.mt.com", "label"
 : "MT Home", "platform" : "mobile", "speed" : 40, "date" : "2016-12-22T14:01:57
.975Z" }
{ "_id" : "585be0da13385513689f704d", "site" : "NBT", "url" : "m.nbt.com", "labe
l" : "NBT Home", "platform" : "mobile", "speed" : 90, "date" : "2016-12-22T12:18
:57.975Z" }
```

The above query will give the result as

```
{
  "_id": {
    "label": "MT Home",
    "platform": "mobile"
  },
  "site": "MT",
  "url": "m.mt.com",
  "speed": 40,
  "date": "2016-12-22T14:01:57.975Z"
}
{
  "_id": {
    "label": "NBT Home",
    "platform": "mobile"
  },
  "site": "NBT",
  "url": "m.nbt.com",
  "speed": 61,
  "date": "2016-12-22T14:18:57.975Z"
}
{
  "_id": {
    "label": "NBT Home",
    "platform": "desktop"
  },
  "site": "NBT",
  "url ": "nbt.com",
  "speed": 75,
  "date": "2016-12-22T14:15:57.975Z"
}
```